# How to include two dates in parenthetical citation without including two dates in references?

Tags: citing, natbib

I am using Springer's [svjour3.cls and spbasic.bst files](https://static.springer.com/sgw/documents/468198/application/zip/LaTeX_DL_468198_01072021.zip). I modified the .bst file to conform to the citation style of the specific Springer journal in which I'm publishing (a variation on APA style). Here's an example of how that looks in the outputted PDF:

[image]

As you can see, I only want to include one date ("2004") after the author's name; the other date ("1988") is mentioned in parentheses.

To achieve this result, here's how the .bib entry looks:

```
@incollection{Lewis1988,
    author = {David Lewis}, 
    pages = {77--103},
    editor = {Peter Ludlow and Yujin Nagasawa and Daniel Stoljar},
    booktitle = {There's Something About Mary: Essays on Phenomenal Consciousness and Frank Jackson's Knowledge Argument},
    year = {2004}, 
    origdate = {1988},
    title = {What Experience Teaches},
    publisher = {Cambridge, MA: MIT Press},
    note = {(Reprinted from ``What experience teaches," 1988, \textit{Proceedings of the Russellian Society}, \textit{13}, pp. 29--57)}
}
```

However, if I cite this entry in my tex file with the command \citep[see, e.g.,][]{Lewis2004}, it only displays the more recent date:

[image]

I'd like it to look like this: "see, e.g., Lewis 1988/2004."

The only way I've found to achieve this result is to include the second date in the "year" field of the .bib entry:

```
year = {1988/2004}
```

But if I do that, it includes the year in the reference entry, and I don't want that:

[image]

How can I achieve the desired result? I suspect that there should be a solution involving the "origdate" element of the .bib entry. I've come across would be solutions involving the \DeclareFieldFormat command, but I can't get them to work in my TeX file, perhaps because I'm using natbib.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `natbib` you can define a citation alias for these sorts of cases. Since you're using a modified `.bst` file, in this example I've just used the `apalike` style, but the solution should work with your modified style too.

The one downside of the basic solution is that the parentheses are hardcoded into the citation, so if you use `citepalias` you will get *(Lewis (1988/2004))* which is probably not what you want.

We can get around this by making the parentheses context sensitive with a conditional.

Since `natbib` doesn't provide corresponding alt commands for the alias citations, if we want an `\citealpalias` command we need to provide one, which is what you figured out. The way I set up the context sensitive parentheses was by setting the conditional on the `\citetalias` command. So if we create a new `\citepalias` command, it will use the "no parentheses" version of the alias.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Lewis1988,
    author = {David Lewis}, 
    pages = {77--103},
    editor = {Peter Ludlow and Yujin Nagasawa and Daniel Stoljar},
    booktitle = {There's Something About Mary: Essays on Phenomenal Consciousness and Frank Jackson's Knowledge Argument},
    year = {2004}, 
    origdate = {1988},
    title = {What Experience Teaches},
    publisher = {Cambridge, MA: MIT Press},
    note = {(Reprinted from ``What experience teaches," 1988, \textit{Proceedings of the Russellian Society}, \textit{13}, pp. 29--57)}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\newif\ifcitep\citeptrue
\newcommand*\altlparen{\ifcitep\else(\fi}
\newcommand*\altrparen{\ifcitep\else)\fi\global\citeptrue}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\citetalias}{\citepfalse}{}{}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\citealpalias{\begingroup
   \NAT@swatrue\let\NAT@ctype\thr@@\NAT@parfalse\NAT@citetp}
\makeatother
\defcitealias{Lewis1988}{Lewis \altlparen 1988/2004\altrparen}

\begin{document}
\citetalias{Lewis1988}
\citepalias{Lewis1988}
\citealpalias{Lewis1988}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks, this helps, but it isn't a complete solution, because I have other entries with the same issue that I use in both \cite{} and \citep{} environments. So I'm not sure how I'd use the citealias with both of them.

Comment: @zblaesi Well yes, that's exactly what I said.  I've updated the answer to make the parentheses context sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I think @AlanMunn just helped solve all my problems, although I'm not quite sure why.

@AlanMunn's recommendation worked. However, one problem remained: sometimes I need to cite the author and year outside of parentheses, as with the \citealt command.

I couldn't figure out how to create a conditional command that does this, but it occurred to me that if I could define a new command in the natbib.sty file that is exactly the same as the \citetalias command but different in name, then I could modify the conditional command for *that* command to remove the parentheses that are ordinarily implemented with the \citetalias command.

So I opened the natbib.sty file and scrolled down to lines 746-747:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\citetalias{\begingroup
\NAT@swafalse\let\NAT@ctype\thr@@\NAT@parfalse\NAT@citetp}
```

Immediately after this, I added the following:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\citetaliasnew{\begingroup
\NAT@swafalse\let\NAT@ctype\thr@@\NAT@parfalse\NAT@citetp}
```

If I use \citetaliasnew together with @AlanMunn's conditional command, it does the same thing as \citealt. But I'm not quite sure why, because I assumed that I'd need to create a new conditional command that operates on \citetaliasnew to produce that result!

I guess the following is happening: since \citetaliasnew is distinct from \citetalias and \citepalias, it somehow satisfies the conditions in the conditional command that removes the parentheses. Maybe someone else can explain it; I don't understand these languages. And if anyone has a more elegant solution that achieves the same result, let me know.

Comment: It's never a good idea to modify `.sty` files that are part of your main distribution. Either make a copy with a different name and put it in your local `texmf` folder, or add the relevant code to your document preamble. This answer isn't really an answer though. It's a reasonable solution to the problem however, and I'm happy to add it to mine and explain why it works.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works!

Comment: If my answer solved your problem it's helpful to other to accept it by clicking on the green checkmark icon beside the answer.

Comment: Got it! I'll do that now.